# How to prevent an array from repeating elements consecutively?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

Shortly, here is what I want :

it returns true when

```
    arr=[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

or

```
    arr=[a, b, a, b, c, d, c, e, a, b]
```

they don't have to be in order.

and false when :

```
    arr=[a, a, b, c, d, d, e, f]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Now what you want??

Comment: I want every next element is different than the previous one, though they can duplicate, but not next to each other.. I think the examples are clear..

Comment: Is this really a duplicate to that question???

Comment: @tsh I don't think so either. OP doesn't want to "jumble" the array, they want to check for consecutive repetitions and return a boolean. Why do some people have such quick trigger-fingers?

Comment: Maybe `a => a.every((n, i) => i === 0 || n !== a[i - 1])`

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: btw, *prevent* vs *check*.

Comment: Right, but they're still talking about "return true/false" and not everyone's a native English speaker :)

Comment: English is my third language and I've just started learning Javascript and this is my first question.. I'm sorry if I typed something wrong.

Comment: but the question remains, what have you tried?

Comment: It's a challenge, so this is only a part of the problem, I'm working on it, and I will give feedback..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test whether all elements in an array pass the test (that is a callback function returning a boolean value). In this case, make sure that the current element being checked is not the same as the previous one (`index - 1`), ignoring the very first element (`!index`).

```js
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
var arr2 = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f"];

function arrayHasConsecitiveRepetition(arrayIn) {
  return arrayIn.every(function(element, index) {
      return !index || element !== arrayIn[index - 1];
  });
}

console.log(arrayHasConsecitiveRepetition(arr1)); // true
console.log(arrayHasConsecitiveRepetition(arr2)); // false
```

You can of course also do it the other way around, using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if at least one element matches the condition, <s>which might actually be better in terms of performance, as it stops evaluating once the condition is true</s>*:

```js
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
var arr2 = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f"];

function arrayHasConsecitiveRepetition(arrayIn) {
  return !arrayIn.some(function(element, index) {
      return index && element === arrayIn[index - 1];
  });
}

console.log(arrayHasConsecitiveRepetition(arr1)); // true
console.log(arrayHasConsecitiveRepetition(arr2)); // false
```

**Actually, it turns out that both methods return immediately once the condition is (not) met, so it's more a matter of taste or style than a matter of performance. I'd prefer to use the first approach in this case as it's clearer to me.*

*From the MDN pages:*

> If such an element is found, the `every` method immediately returns `false`.
>
> If such an element is found, `some()` immediately returns `true`.

Comment: "which might actually be better in terms of performance, as it stops evaluating once the condition is true" Won't `Array#every` stop evaluating once the condition is false?

Comment: That is indeed a good question, I hadn't thought of that. And it turns out you're right:  `If such an element is found, the every method immediately returns false.`! So I guess it's not a matter of performance at all, but a matter of taste.

Comment: Updated the answer to address that

Comment: so the .some and .every saves the time of making an if.. else ? right? I'm a newbie so I'm trying to understand what I'm reading and typing... 
Also if you don't mind, why wouldn't the answer of Monika work? that was the very first thing that came up to my mind... Thanks

Comment: It helps keep the code shorter. You could also loop over the array elements and check with if/else, yes.

Comment: Monika's answer is not JavaScript.

Comment: ah oops, I didn't pay attention, I meant I used : if (walk[i]===walk[i+1]) { return false }
if (walk[i]===walk[i-1]) { return false }

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
const arr2 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

function checkArr(arr) {
  let previous;

  const check = !arr.some(letter => {
      if (letter === previous) {
          return true;
      }

      previous = letter;
  });

  console.log(check);
}

checkArr(arr1); // true
checkArr(arr2); // false
```

Comment: Note that when the first element is `undefined`, it will return `false` even if the second element is not `undefined`. You'd probably want to check for `previous && letter === previous`